# Aobut PHP Description Resource Path Location Type syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting 'EOF' timer.php /LZtimer line 33 PHP Syntax Error

Tags: php, eclipse

When I build a form in PHP, Ecilpse told me "Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting 'EOF'   timer.php   /LZtimer    line 33 PHP Syntax Error
"

```
#创建输入框
<form action="" method="post">
<input name="starttime" type="num"size="15" value="start time" maxlength="25"
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: looks like raw html when you are inside a php block. you dont cloese the php block untill line 38

Comment: You have not closed input tag in line no. 34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input tag is not closed. Please change

```
<input name="starttime" type="num"size="15" value="start time" maxlength="25"
```

to

```
<input name="starttime" type="num" size="15" value="start time" maxlength="25">
```

Also, you need a space between attributes type and size

```
type="num"[SPACE HERE]size="15"
```

Comment: well that's the HTML errors, how about the php one?

Comment: please, share the content of timer.php